# Django dependent drop down not functioning properly

Tags: django, django-forms

Django noob

I am currently attempting to implement a dependent drop down list for car models - manufactures
[I am following this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html)

I have the form displaying properly but the issue I am facing is if I select a manufacture no models are displayed.

I have spent a bunch of time attempting to solve this and I am out of ideas

All feedback welcome!

forms.py

```
from blog.models import Post, Manufactures, Models

class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = 'title', 'manufacture', 'model', 'content', 'image', 'aspiration'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['model'].queryset = Models.objects.none()
```

models.py

```
    class Manufactures(models.Model):
    manufacture_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    manufacture = models.CharField(max_length=55)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.manufacture

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('db-manufactures', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Models(models.Model):
    model_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    model_manufacture = models.ForeignKey(Manufactures, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.model

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog-models', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Views.py

```
    def loadModels(request):
    manufacture_id = request.GET.get('model_manufacture')
    models = Models.objects.filter(manufacture_id = manufacture_id)
    return render(request, 'model_dropdown_list.html', {'models': models})

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Post,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

model_dropdown_list.html

```
    <option value="">---------</option>
    {% for model in models %}
    <option value="{{ model.pk }}">{{ model.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}

post_form.html

    {% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="post" id="modelForm" data-models-url="{% url 'ajax' %}" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Create Post</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#id_manufacture").change(function () {
        var url = $("#PostForm").attr("data-models-url");  // get the url of the `load_cities` view
        var manufactureId = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input

        $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
            url: url,                    // set the url of the request (= localhost:8000/hr/ajax/load-cities/)
            data: {
                'manufacture': manufactureID       // add the country id to the GET parameters
            },
            success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
                $("#id_model").html(data);  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
            }
        });

    });
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('ajax/load-models', views.loadModels, name='ajax')
]
```

**Update**

The error was in my post_form.html I had use a lowercase d and not an uppercase

```
<script>
$("#id_manufacture").change(function () {
    var url = $("#PostForm").attr("data-models-url");  
    var manufactureId = $(this).val(); !!!lowercase "d" on manufactureId

    $.ajax({                      
        url: url,                    
        data: {
            'manufacture_id': manufactureID !!!uppercase "D"       
        },
        success: function (data) {   
            $("#id_model").html(data);  
        }
    });

});
```

**New Issue**

[image]

It seems to be making the correct call and is grabbing the proper id except it is behaving strangely. When I select a manufacture it runs the request once. If I then change my mind and select a different manufacture it runs the call twice(with the correct id) and so on.

except when on the page after you select a manufacture the model drop down is empty

[image]

**Solution**

```
def loadModels(request):
model_manufacture_id = request.GET.get('model_manufacture')
models = Models.objects.filter(model_manufacture_id=model_manufacture_id) #orderby?
return render(request, 'blog/model_dropdown_list.html', {'models': models})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like in the Tutorial, but i can't say 100% because your `urls.py` is missing. Did you check developer console? Try to `console.log(manufactureId)` and `console.log(url)` to check if you have the right data needed

also what i can see -> your model dont have a property called  `name`, it is called `model` In your Models class - so you need to get `model.model` Instead of `model.name` in `model_dropdown_list.html`

```
class Models(models.Model):
    model_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  --> model = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    model_manufacture = models.ForeignKey(Manufactures, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.model

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog-models', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

The template has to look like this:

```
    <option value="">---------</option>
    {% for model in models %}
    <option value="{{ model.pk }}">{{ model.model }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
```

PS: what i can See, you want to access your form with `$("#PostForm")` but it’s Id is  `modelForm` - please check your namings :)

Comment: Added urls.py. Thanks for the reply! Just want to make sure I understand what you are saying. In the tutorial the models have a name attribute. In mine I do not have them called "name" but "manufacture" and "model" so I have to go about retrieving this items differently? so I should be calling it like {{ model.model.pk }} ? Just confused because I haven't heard of this before.

Comment: Nope you‘re giving a list of models, each model has following attributes:

`model_id` (which is your pk),  `model`, `model_manufacture`

You access them as `model.model_id` or `model.pk`

Comment: PS: if you just want to use integer ids, you don’t have to create an attribute. Django automatically creates an integer id for you which can be accessed via `<model>.id` or `<model>.pk`

Comment: Ah I just misunderstood what you wrote, thank you! Unfortunately it's still not functioning correctly... going to do some more testing

Comment: If you have further questions, you can come back :) - I would check the endpoint `ajax/load-models` directly via browser if everything works fine, and debug the template/JavaScript code if the url is set correctly as well as the other attributes, and if the model Dropdown is filled but not shon